# Transforming List of dicts to nested list of dicts

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a base data like this, unique id in the data base in d_id. (data named as 'input')

```
[
    {
      "d_id": "a1", 
      "d_name": "Fishing", 
      "location": "ABC", 
      "location_id": 1, 
      "rest_id": 2, 
      "rest_name": "Grilling"
    }, 
    {
      "d_id": "a2", 
      "d_name": "catching", 
      "location": "ABC", 
      "location_id": 1, 
      "rest_id": 3, 
      "rest_name": "Kayaking"
    }, 
    {
      "d_id": "a3", 
      "d_name": "Fishing2", 
      "location": "ABC", 
      "location_id": 1, 
      "rest_id": 2, 
      "rest_name": "Grilling"
    },
    {
      "d_id": "a4", 
      "d_name": "Watering", 
      "location": "DEF", 
      "location_id": 2, 
      "rest_id": 4, 
      "rest_name": "Careoff"
    }
]
```

I want to make dictionary as following, which is a nested json categorized by location_id, rest_id and d_id:

localities would have multiple locations, each location would have multiple rest_id's , and each rest would have multiple d_id's

```
{ 
    "localities" : [
        { 
            "location": "ABC",
            "location_id": 1,
            "rest_details": [
                {
                    "rest_id": 2, 
                    "rest_name": "Grilling", 
                    "d_details" : [
                        {
                            "d_id" : "a1",
                            "d_name" : "Fishing"
                        },
                        {
                            "d_id" : "a3",
                            "d_name" : "Fishing2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "rest_id": 3,
                    "rest_name": "Kayaking",
                    "d_details" : [
                        {
                            "d_id" : "a2",
                            "d_name" : "catching"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "location" : "DEF",
            "location_id": 2,
            "rest_details": [
                {
                    "rest_id" : 4,
                    "rest_name" : "Careoff",
                    "d_details" : [
                        {
                            "d_id" : "a4",
                            "d_name": "Watering"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I attempted the following over past couple of days, wherein i tried to segregate the data into location_info, rest_info, d_info:

## for location info

```
location_info = []
location_fields = {'location', 'location_id', 'd_id', 'rest_id' }
for item in input:
    loc = {key:value for key,value in item.items() if key in  location_fields}
location_info.append(loc)
```

## for unique location_info entries

```
k=1
while k<len(location_info):
    if location_info[k] == location_info[k-1]:
        location_info.pop(k-1)
    else:
        k = k+1
```

## for rest_info

```
rest_info = []
rest_fields = {'rest_name','rest_id', 'd_id', 'loc_id'}
for item in input:
    res = {key:value for key,value in item.items() if key in restaurant_fields}
    restaurant_info.append(res)
```

## for d_info

```
d_info = []
d_fields = {'d_id', 'd_name', 'location_id'}
for item in input:
    dis = {key:value for key,value in item.items() if key in d_fields}
d_info.append(dis)
```

## for merging rest_info with location_info

```
for ta in location_info:
    for tb in rest_info:
        if ta['loc_id'] == tb['loc_id']:
            ta['localities'] = tb
```

tb doesnt produce the first leg of the expected result.

Comment: You should try for what you want first and then seek or help. And if you had attempted it then please care to share it.

Comment: You're basically asking people to do this for you. This site is about helping people with specific problems, not a free coding service.

Comment: @TanveerAlam intention was to seek help on the matter and i stand corrected as a new user. apologies. i have added the info which i have attempted. in case you could guide would be of great help.

Comment: @PaulRooney  intention was to seek help on the matter and i stand corrected as a new user. apologies. i have added the info which i have attempted. in case you could guide would be of great help.

Comment: @TanveerAlam : seems i am missing something very fundamental here related to list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is sprinkled with errors. You should at least run each of the snippets yourself and see if they give the desired output of the step (because they don't).

Apart from that your approach seems unnecessarily complicated. I would try it like this:

```
locations = {}
for elem in input:
    rest_details = []
    curr_rest_detail = {"rest_id": elem["rest_id"], "rest_name":elem["rest_name"], "d_details":[{"d_id":elem["d_id"], "d_name":elem["d_name"]}]}
    try:
        rest_details = locations[elem["location_id"]]["rest_details"]
        rest_detail_exists = False
        for detail in rest_details:
            if detail["rest_id"] == curr_rest_detail["rest_id"]:
                rest_detail_exists = True
                detail["d_details"].append({"d_id":elem["d_id"], "d_name":elem["d_name"]})
                break
        if not rest_detail_exists:
            rest_details.append(curr_rest_detail)
    except KeyError:
        locations[elem["location_id"]] = {"location": elem["location"], "location_id":elem["location_id"], "rest_details":[curr_rest_detail]}

result = {"localities": [value for value in locations.values()]}
```

This code basically iterates over the elements of your input and adds an entry whenever the entry does not exist yet. If it already exists, it only appends the additional information.

Comment: @x squared - thanks indeed. it works much better than what i was trying to do. Will learn more about try and except.